# How to receive a mail on new orders?

Tags: ecommerce, prestashop

When a customer makes a new order he receives a couple of confirmation mails, but I (as shop administrator) don't receive any. How can I make prestashop to send me a new mail when customers make new orders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the [Mail Alerts module](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS14/Managing+Modules#ManagingModules-Administration).

There's also an [Order Alerts](http://addons.prestashop.com/en/shipping-logistics/2090-order-alerts.html) module that lets you set up rules for notifications, if you need something more granular.